# CodeIgniter url_suffix issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working a CodeIgniter project version 2.5. I add a url suffix in `config.php` as `$config['url_suffix'] = '.asp';`. When I go to `https://localhost:81/project/sample` it works fine but if I go to `https://localhost:81/project/sample.asp` it returns `The requested resource /project/sample.asp was not found on this server.`
What's wrong here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In config.php, you can add any of `url_suffix`

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '.asp';
$config['url_suffix'] = '.html';
$config['url_suffix'] = '.php';
```

This will work fine when you use it.

Still failed

Goto -> `routes.php`

```
$route['project/sample'] = 'project/sample.asp';
```